# How to remove date from filename linux

Tags: linux, shell

I have a scenario where I want to remove date from filename

Lets take an example 1 :

```
ABC_2019_06_12.txt
```

Lets take an example 2 :

```
ABCDEF_202012040120456.txt
```

using cut I cannot delete required text
how to cut to get the required below output like below

```
ABC.txt
ABCDEF.txt
```

One command which should work for all scenario which ever filename it is

My solution which I worked is to read the number of position and cut that part but I don't find it effective any other solution will be appreciated

Comment: Are underscores a valid part of the filename? If not you can cut the content after the underscore.

Comment: @BlackPearl yes how to do that

Answer (score 0):

In `bash` you can cut off the part starting with underscore:

```
$ filename=ABC_2019_06_12.txt
$ filename=${filename%%_*}
$ echo $filename
ABC
```

Comment: it partially worked …. what ever may be the string it should get cut …. for example if I give name of file like ABC_EFG_2019_245.txt …. then also your above code cut only first three letters ABC it should be ABC_EFG.txt